# unreal engine -waitmutes-2015 exited with code 255

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

when i make a new c++ project in ue4(doesnt matter version because same problem with most 4.8-4.11)it gives me:

*The following modules are missing or build with a different engine version:UE4Editor-test.dll
Would you like to rebuild them now?*

i press yes and it gives me:
*test could not be compiled.try rebuilding from source manually.*

when i build the "source" in VS2015 , i get
*:MSB3073 The command ""C/:Program Files (x86)\Epic Games\4.11\Engine\Build\BatchFiles\Rebuild.bat" testEditor Win64 Development "C:\Users\usr\Documents\Unreal Projects\test\test.uproject" -waitmutex -2015" exited with code 255.*

so i cant open the project made for C++ (no for blueprints) in the editor.

Any help appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this is a known issue:
https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/185309/cant-compile.html (I know it's old but it seems to be a problem UE4 likes to run into sometimes)

Scraped from the link  <strike>below</strike>  *above* for attempting to fix this error:

```
Rebuild your project: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5J4ocSzoDK8 (delete your .sln files and your Binary/Win64 folder. Right-click .uproject and "generate visual studio files"
```

If this doesnt work, if you're using the Unreal Launcher: try building from source: https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Programming/Development/BuildingUnrealEngine/

If this still doesn't work, I'd reinstall Visual Studio (update it to newest version if you're on an older version) and try again with a from-source version of UE4. (I sure hope this last one works. VS + UE4 setup is a hefty download)

Hopefully one of these helps :)